# Can a Win32 program converted to UWP by the desktop bridge ever run on ARM?

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

Not all Win32 programs rely on API calls that are unavailable in UWP/ARM, but it appears that the only CPU choices for converted programs are X86 and X64. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you are correct. Apps converted using the Desktop Bridge (aka Project Centennial) could run only on x86/x64 systems. Actually, Desktop Bridge doesn't really convert a Win32 app into native UWP app but it packs it as an UWP so it could be distributed through Windows Store.

However, it may be possible to run these apps on ARM processors in the future since Microsoft is developing desktop Windows 10 that is running on ARM processors and is able to run even x86/x64 apps on those processors using JIT.

But if you are asking about Win32 apps on phones, I doubt they will ever be enabled to run on them.

Comment: And yet my understanding is that "converted" apps could add features from the UWP APIs that aren't available to Win32 apps. So perhaps the truth is more nuanced. Or maybe my understanding  is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically how it works. You can read more about using UWP APIs in Win32 app in [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application).

Comment: Very interesting link. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to inform that it, indeed, does not work on ARM. I converted MFC App built for ARM using Desktop App Converter, packaged and signed. But it fails to install on ARM device and gives `package targets wrong architecture` error